# why is carrier wave 0.9.0 resampling jpgs when converting to pdf

Tags: pdf, carrierwave, minimagick

in v0.8.0 doing a 

    `process :convert => "pdf"`

on a jpg results in a the jpg being stored as is inside the pdf.  I.e. the PDF is just a wrapper around the pdf.

after v0.9.0 the same operation results in a much smaller / lower resolution resampled jpg being stored in the pdf.

Same version of minimagick is begin used throughout.

the following two blocks are clipped from the resulting pdfs the first block was generated with carrierwave 0.9.0, the second was 0.8.0. That was the only change in the code / gemfile. The file being converted to PDF is a 600 DPI image. It appears that carrierwave 0.9.0 by default is using a dpi of 72 when converting images to PDF...

```
/Type /XObject
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Filter [ /RunLengthDecode ]
/Height 522
/Length 317714
/Name /Im0
/SMask 8 0 R
/Subtype /Image
/Width 378


/Type /XObject
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Filter [ /DCTDecode ]
/Height 4350
/Length 649502
/Name /Im0
/Subtype /Image
/Width 3150
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around:  replace 
    process :convert => :pdf 
with
    process :convert_to_pdf

and add

```
def convert_to_pdf # copied from carrierwave code base
  # @format = :pdf # this line causes the problem... why?
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.format(:pdf) 
    img
  end
end
```

In otherwords create your own convert function that DOES NOT have @format = :pdf which is what is causing the problem.  @format = :pdf I believe is only needed if you are chaining manipulations together.